# Problems with replacing top post battery with side post version?

Tags: battery

2007 Nissan Maxima ... Someone  gave me a new delco side connection battery. So is there a surge or other danger of modifying with attaching the posts and running a positive cable extension about 12 inches long to the factory battery harness which of course includes a fuse box ... So yes I am contemplating installing a side connection battery in place of factory set up of a top post battery...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you asking if there are any issues with attaching a side post battery to a car which normally had a top post?

Answer (score 1):

At its heart, a battery is a battery. The differences are going to be voltage and the power it provides. As long as the battery can provide the amount of energy which is needed by the car to start it, it should work just fine. You'll also need to deal with the physical attributes of both the battery (footprint) as well as ensure the positive side post doesn't get near a grounding location. Other than that, it should work just fine.